# Array subset in aggregation framework pipeline

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

In a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13529323/obtaining-group-result-with-group-count) I wanted to obtain a count of the resulting groups using pipeline operations. As suggested, I used the following:

```
db.test.aggregate(
    {$unwind: '$tags'}, 
    {$group:{_id: '$tags', count:{$sum:1}}},
    {$project:{tmp:{tag:'$_id', count:'$count'}}}, 
    {$group:{_id:null, total:{$sum:1}, data:{$addToSet:'$tmp'}}}
)
```

Now having known the count, I would like to display the results by page so I would only need a subset of `data`. My initial thought would be using `$slice` on `data` within a `$project` pipeline like:

```
...
{$project: {data : { $slice: [20,20] }, total: 1}
```

But it appears that `$slice` is not a valid operation for `$project`. I tried a workaround by doing:

```
db.test.aggregate(
    {$unwind: '$tags'}, 
    {$group:{_id: '$tags', count:{$sum:1}}},
    {$project:{tmp:{tag:'$_id', count:'$count'}}}, 
    {$group:{_id:null, total:{$sum:1}, data:{$addToSet:'$tmp'}}},
    {$unwind: '$data'},
    {$skip: 20},
    {$limit: 20}
)
```

But as it appears, I performed another `$unwind` pipeline. Is there a better solution to achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is currently (as at MongoDB 2.2) no [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/) operator to `$slice` or take a subset of an array.

You will need to use a workaround such as:

- your use of `$skip` and `$limit` in the `aggregate()` pipeline
- manipulation of the results in your application code.
- implementing the aggregation using [Map/Reduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/map-reduce/)

There is an existing feature request in the MongoDB issue tracker that you can upvote/watch: [SERVER-6074: Allow $slice operator in $project](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6074).

Answer (score 0):

As Stennie told, there is no `$slice` for an aggregation framework in **2.2 version** of mongo, but in the upcomming **3.2 version** of mongo they added it.

So now you can use [$slice in aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.2-reference/#exp._S_slice). To return elements from either the start or end of the array: `{ $slice: [ <array>, <n> ] }`
To return elements from the specified position in the array: `{ $slice: [ <array>, <position>, <n> ] }`.

And a couple of examples from the mongo page:

```
{ $slice: [ [ 1, 2, 3 ], 1, 1 ] }   // [ 2 ]
{ $slice: [ [ 1, 2, 3 ], -2 ] }     // [ 2, 3 ]
{ $slice: [ [ 1, 2, 3 ], 15, 2 ] }  // [  ]
{ $slice: [ [ 1, 2, 3 ], -15, 2 ] } // [ 1, 2 ]
```